# Unions alternatives in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm running this query in mysql, but it takes quite some time to execute (0.797 sec). Which is a way too long. I believe that the root problem of my query is that im using too many UNIONS and because of that I'm loading the same tables over and over again. Is there a better implementation of this? So far I was trying to use WITH, but its not supported in MySQL, so that won't work

```
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND
        `Preferred Positions`='ST'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 3
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='CAM'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='LM'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='RM'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='CDM'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='RB'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='LB'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='CB'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
    SELECT 
        Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
    FROM 
        fifa_challenege.completedataset 
    WHERE 
        Nationality='Argentina'
    AND 
        `Preferred Positions`='GK'
    ORDER BY 
        Overall DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: What sort of data does the overall column hold?

Comment: Ususally ints or strings. Basically players ratings, where they play, and things like that

Comment: Rather than adjusting the query itself (which doesn't look to be too "busy"), I'd suggest that the data is what is causing the delay.   If you're dealing with large quantities of rows, you'll benefit from using indexes to enable quicker result retrieval (i.e. indexes on Nationality and Preferred Position)

Comment: Why is it important to order by overall desc ?

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison its the overall rating number from 0 - 100

Comment: @ChrisJ this is a good point, thanks

Comment: Because of the use of `LIMIT` in each subquery, it's very hard to do away with the `UNION`. **IF** you can skip the LIMIT requirements, then it's much much easier

Comment: @JacquesAmar what is an alternative to limit? I could always just cut the array when i get it on my backend side

Comment: If this is slow, it's because some of the subqueries themselves are slow. Combining 12 results should be easy. So work on optimizing each subquery.

Comment: As @ChrisJ said, the underlaying data structure will need to be changed. You need exactly 3 `ST` based on `Overall`. The way *I* would do it is to add a column called `rank` and prep-populate ranking at the time of data entry (if feasible of course). That's a one time shot. Then another table that lookup `Preferred Position` and `max_ranking`. Then every `SELECT` will check the `Preferred Positions` and max ranking, linked to the second table. Retrieval will be as fast DB allows. Let me know if you want me to make this an official answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. add a column called `rank` to `completedataset` and pre-populate that with the ranking per `Nationality`, `Preferred Positions` and `Overall`. this is best achieved by another language than MySQL
2. Create a table called `Positions` With `Position` (PRIMARY KEY) and `max_rank` and pre-fill that.

Like this

```
  CREATE TABLE Positions
  (Position CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  max_rank TINYINT DEFAULT 1);
```

Obviously Populate :

```
INSERT INTO Positions
  ('ST', 3),
  ('CAM', 1),
  ('LM', 1),
  ('RM', 1),
  ('DCM', 1),
  ('RB', 1),
  ('LB', 1),
  ('CB', 2),
  ('GK', 1);
```

Your new query

```
 SELECT 
    Name, Overall, Club, Wage, Nationality, `Preferred Positions`
FROM 
    fifa_challenege.completedataset D
LEFT JOIN Positions P
   ON P.Position=D.`Preferred Positions`
WHERE 
    Nationality='Argentina'
    AND D.rank<=P.max_rank
ORDER BY 
  P.Position, 
  D.Overall DESC
```